# Improper format of datetime column while loading data from mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, json, datetime

I am loading the data from mysql database using python - mysql.connector library,
and I want to export this data into json file.

Though, the date gets retrieved in this format -
datetime.datetime( 2019, 9, 5, 22, 23, 1 )

how do i convert it into proper Datetime format so that I can later export it in json format?

Also, there are like 23 columns in the record, how do I serialize the json properly after doing all the type conversions for the date?

meaning , this is what i get currently :-

```
{
'trips_id': 1 , 
'driver_id': 2, 
'starttrip_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 22, 23, 1), 
'endtrip_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 22, 27, 29) 
}
```

i want to have it like this :-

```
{
'trips_id': 1 , 
'driver_id': 2, 
'starttrip_date': 2019-09-05 22:23:01, 
'endtrip_date': 2019-09-05 22:27:29 
}
```

so that i can export it properly into json file.

Comment: Compose needed JSON on MySQL side, and only retrieve ready-to-use JSON onto python side.

Comment: Hey @Akina, thanks a lot for the suggestion, hat I did was that I processed the retrieved in a dataframe and then dumped it in a json file.Seemed to help my case.